# How can I use Tripadvisor Content API to attain location related info quickly, in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I've seen other StackOverflow threads, use *HTTP Get* to access source code of web pages. But obviously this can take a while, as this requires plentiful *download time* and *string manipulation techniques*.

I've not made use of Tripadvisor Content API before. 
So an example which could possibly accomplish something similar to described below, would be incredibly helpful. Thanks

The data I would like to attain from TripAdvisor within Android is:

for a particular location (e.g. by lon and lat) e.g. Prague Bohemia etc.

A List of:

- Attraction Types *within that location*
- Ranked locations, for attraction types *within that location*

As shown on this page:

tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g274707-Activities-Prague_Bohemia.html

Example of *HTTP GET* described above:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: just do a GET request to http://api.tripadvisor.com/api//partner/2.0/location/2226812,233835,3177246/attractions?key=<PARTNER_KEY>

Comment: You have to request access to the API at https://www.tripadvisor.com/RegistrationPage-a_partnerKey.1-a_url.__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__APIAccessSupport-a_urlKey.c14d08bc080904022

Comment: Alternatively, you can scrape a cut down version of the page using the AJAX API that the web site uses. For example, http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/AttractionsAjax-g274707-Activities-c49